# iPhone 6 mail app delays

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, iphone

I am using iPhone 6 native app as my email client. I recently did the latest update and I have noticed that I've been receiving my email notifications a bit late or delayed. The notifications are sometimes taking about 20 minutes!

At first, I first thought it was a problem with my carrier but on the contrary. They claim that it had something to do with the email client.

I know many people are probably wondering why I don't just use another email client, but for specific reasons, this is the app that I have to use as a mail client.
Is anyone else seeing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that your iPhone is only fetching new data from the server only every so often, like every hour. To fix this, go into Settings->Mail, Contacts, Calendars->Fetch New Data and make sure that "Push" is enabled. Some mail services don't support Push, so the "Fetch" schedule below would be used. Scroll down and select "Every 15 Minutes" under the "Fetch" pane. That's a fast as you'll get notifications for mail that doesn't support Push, but you can always check for mail manually in the Mail app. Also, I should note that enabling Push and more frequent mail Fetching will result in worse battery life.

[image]

Comment: @Leyth What mail service are you using?

Comment: I am using the native iOS `mail app`.

Comment: @Leyth I know that you're using the Mail app,  I mean what service are you using (iCloud, Yahoo, Gmail etc.)?

Comment: I use gmail. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

[Gmail](https://appsto.re/cl/iRBmz.i), [Inbox](https://itunes.apple.com/app/inbox-by-gmail/id905060486?l=en&mt=8) and [Notion](https://itunes.apple.com/app/notion-email-intelligence/id981989351?l=en&mt=8) apps get Gmail based email on push, as opposed to iOS Mail app that is only able to fetch it every 15 minutes.